Sum of bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space is bounded
I am trying to prove that $B(\mathcal{H})$ is closed under operator addition using only the notion of boundedness that we have for topological vector spaces, and I am running into difficulties.
I believe that we can use the norm induced by the inner product on $\mathcal{H}$ so that we are allowed the ordinary definition of boundedness, but I am specifically trying to avoid this out of curiosity.
Let $f,g \in B(\mathcal{H})$, and let $W$ be a bounded subset of $\mathcal{H}$. Then we know there exist $r_f, r_g > 0$ such that for any neighborhood $V$ of $0$, $x \in f(W)$, $y \in g(W)$, $c_f, c_g \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|c_f| \geq r_f$ and $|c_g| \geq r_g$, there exists $v_f, v_g \in V$ such that
$$
x = c_f v_f, \\
y = c_g v_g.
$$
We want to prove there exists $r > 0$ such that for any $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|c| \geq r$, there exists $v \in V$ such that
$$
x + y = cv.
$$
I can choose $r = r_f + r_g$ and $c = c_f + c_g$ and write
$$
x + y = c v_f + c v_g = c(v_f + v_g).
$$
But here I am stuck, because we have no guarantee that $v_f + v_g \in V$. Is this approach viable?

If $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ and $v_f \in V$, then there exists some neighborhood $V’$ of $0$ such that $v_f + V’ \subset V$. Choose $v_g$ from $V’$ instead.
